# TortoiseSVN - Database locked

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Uso o TortoiseSVN com Windows, quando tento dar um Update na minha cópia de trabalho é apresentada a seguinte mensagem:

> Update Working copy '[Diretório da copia de trabalho]' locked. '[Diretório da minha cópia de trabalho]' is already 
>   locked. Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.

Não consigo executar um Cleanup na cópia de trabalho, ao tentar realizar o cleanup é exibida a seguinte mensagem

> Cleanup failed to process the following pats: [Diretorio da minha copia de trabalho] locked.
>   Please execute Cleanup Command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre quando uma determinada tarefa é terminada no meio do processo o que gera um problema no banco de dados do próprio tortoiseSVN.

Para resolver a questão, utilize algum gerenciador de banco de dados SQLite para abrir o banco de dados wc.db que fica no diretório `"\.svn\"` que fica na raiz da sua cópia de trabalho (Diretório oculto).

Procure a tabela `WC_LOCK` e delete todos os registros desta tabela. Ou execute o seguinte comando:

```
DELETE FROM WC_LOCK
```

Após a remoção dos dados, execute um Cleanup e um Update na pasta de trabalho.